# Renaming a subsite (Name & change its URL) will not allow me to save it as templete

Tags: 2013, development, administration, site-template

I was working on a subsite and i use to save it as templete without any problem, now i decide to change the sub site name and URL , so i rename it from CustomerPortal to CustomerportalTemplete.

But now after the subsite rename, if i try to save the subsite as template i got the following exception :-

```
Error exporting the site field named "HashTags".
```

now i think i got an idea what might be causing this , now my site columns before the rename have a column named "HashTags" as follow, this column seems will be created automatically by SharePoint on the subsite level:-

[image]

but after the sub site rename i got many duplicates of this site columns as follow:-

[image]

now if i remove the sub site columns named HashTags, and i try to save the subsite as template again i will get the following exception :-

```
Error exporting the site field named "HashTags_0"."
```

so the error is mentioning `HashTags_0` instead of "HashTags". and also when i try to delete one of the duplicates all the other duplicates columns will be removed automatically
so can anyone adivce on this please?

Comment: you can use the SharePoint manager from codeplex and delete the column or also check this http://www.sharepointfix.com/2011/04/powershell-script-to-delete-site.html

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE but the question is why i got this behavior,  I mean why the column got created and why it got duplicated when i rename ad change the subsite URL!! is this a buh in SP ? or what happened exactly?  i did not use sharepoint manager before, but sure what is about and how it will be useful in my case?

Comment: also the link you provide talks about removing a site collection column, while in my case it is a subsite column,, will this work ?